# How I can use a Image as Background for my html mail in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, attachment

I have a Question to send mails with html and attachment as an embedded image. 
I don't know how I can use the Picture from my images folder as Background for a div.

here my code:

```
SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
            SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

            oMail.From = "test@emailarchitect.net";

            oMail.To = "<my email>";

            oMail.Subject = "test";

            SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("<smtp server>");

            try
            {
               // Attachment header = oMail.AddAttachment("d:\\mail_header.jpg");
                Attachment header = oMail.AddAttachment("images/mail_header.jpg"); // this don't work
                Attachment oAttachment = oMail.AddAttachment("d:\\bg_content.jpg");
                Attachment Footer = oMail.AddAttachment("d:\\mail_footer.jpg");

                string contentID_header = "header";
                header.ContentID = contentID_header; 

                string contentID = "test001@host";
                oAttachment.ContentID = contentID;

                string contentID_footer = "footer";
                Footer.ContentID = contentID_footer; 

//how I can use a pic as background

                oMail.HtmlBody = "<html><body>"+
                                    "<div style='background-image:url(" + contentID_header + ");width: 800px;height: 50px'></div>" +
                                    "<div><img src=\"cid:" + contentID + "\"></div>" +
                                    "<div><img src=\"cid:" + contentID_footer + "\"></div>" +
                                    "</body></html>";

                oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail); 

            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                txtSimulate.Text = ep.Message; 
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code, it is working nice using **LinkedResources** with **Alternateviews**.
Much better than hardcoding CIDS.

Check it:

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage Mensaje = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage("mail@host.com",DireccionCorreo);

System.Net.Mail.AlternateView htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body, null, "text/html");


System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource logo = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource("logoimage.jpg");
logo.ContentId = "logoimage";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logo);

System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource logoExchange = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource("logoexchange.png");
logoExchange.ContentId = "logoexchange";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(logoExchange);

System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource tut1 = new System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(Application.StartupPath + "/OutlookGuide/tut1.jpg");
tut1 .ContentId = "tut1";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(tut1 );

System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource tut2 = new   System.Net.Mail.LinkedResource(Application.StartupPath + "/OutlookGuide/tut2.jpg");
tut2.ContentId = "tut2";
htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(tut2);


Mensaje.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Comment: yes but my code work, too. only "<div style='background-image:url(" + contentID_header + ");width: 800px;height: 50px'></div>" don't work and I want that the div have the background

Comment: @Tarasov even am facing exactly same problem have you solved this??

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about asp.net but with PHP we do it by converting the image to Base64 encoding and then using

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to give full path of the image .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I found this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/inkrajesh.aspx).

But basicly, "embed" the image in the email message itself, you'll want to add it as a [Linked Resource](http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.4.aspx) and reference the attached resource in the email's HTML.